# Design c# - Wanting to display in another method

Tags: c#

```
public void ShowOther(String input)
{
    char [] holder = input.ToCharArray();

    for (int i = 0; i < holder.Length; i++)
    {
        if (other.Contains(holder[i]))
        {
            holder.SetValue('^', i);
        }
        if (goodChars.Contains(holder[i]))
        {
            holder.SetValue(' ', i);
        }
        Console.Write(holder.GetValue(i));
    }
}
```

So, right now I have this method as such. What I want to do is remove my printing from this method while maintaining the contents of the `char[]` holder.

Would changing return type to a `char[]` and then placing my return after the for loop work? Or am I off track and could do something simpler?

Comment: Which pieces of your code do you consider as "printing" (`Console.Write`, or also `holder.SetValue`)? And why do you want to move the printing to another method (it is called `Show...` after all)? What is your issue with the method as it is?

Comment: @stakx I'm assuming the `Console.Write`. The `holder.SetValue` is simply a strange way of assigning to `holder[i]`, if you leave that out, there's nothing else that the function would do.

Comment: @stakx I was just wanting to consolidate my output into a single method and this was impeding that goal. It was as simple as I thought, though. I must have had a typo when attempting to return it before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that would work.

```
public void ShowOther(string input)
{
    Console.Write(GetOther(input));
}

public char[] GetOther(String input)
{
    char [] holder = input.ToCharArray();

    for (int i = 0; i < holder.Length; i++)
    {
        if (other.Contains(holder[i]))
        {
            holder.SetValue('^', i);
        }
        if (goodChars.Contains(holder[i]))
        {
            holder.SetValue(' ', i);
        }
    }

    return holder;
}
```

I'm not sure how you'd use `GetOther` in a meaningful way without printing, so I don't know if this refactoring is actually useful for you, but you're probably a better judge of that than I am.

Comment: Thanks, for some reason when I was attempting this before it kept telling me i++ was inaccessible. Yet it works flawlessly now.